# Google Cloud Datastore Console - Service Unavailable 503

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-client

I am working on a Google Datastore integration and I have the following issue with Google's console. I have another Datastore project that is working correctly. I just dont understand why it returns `503 Service Unavailable`. I created the project via my Google Accounts, so I am the owner of the account, it should be working. Any ideas?

Here is the issue:
[image]

Comment: does your `datasets` matches the `project name` and your `application id`?

Comment: are you using a domain restricted application?

Comment: @proppy, no and my datasets is correct. I do have another instance of the same application that uses a different Datastore project and this one is all working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me. I added one project which was basically called something like **my-project** for production and **my-project-dev** for development. My project is working perfectly, but  **my-project-dev** is not (refer to screenshots above).

So I created a new project and took the name that Google Datastore generated and that worked.